# Which memory profiler will tell me what is collected in each generation?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I've recently become curious about exactly which objects are collected in which generation. It's been a while since I last used a profiler, which I think was SciTech. I don't recall it showing a breakdown of collections sorted by generation number, but I may be wrong.

Before I go and install a whole bunch of profilers, does anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **WinDbg**. There's an extension called SOSex ([SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/)) which extends the basic commands provided by the standard SOS.DLL debugger extension.

Specifically, it has a command, **!dumpgen**, that dumps the contents of the specified generation.

Also, with SOS **!FindRoots** you can set a breakpoint when the GC is about to collect a generation.

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains dotTrace is equally good as ANTS. Just in case You wanted to have more choice.

Answer (score 1):

[ANTS Performance Profiler 6.2](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
.NET code profiler: Speed up the performance of your .NET applications

Comment: And you're certain I can look up Gen2 and get a list of objects?

Answer (score 1):

I use ANTS - it's made up of 2 separate profilers, a performance one and a memory one. You'd need to use [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) to look at object collection. That definitely lets you examine different generations separately.